# Wordpress template restored by mistake

Tags: templates

I clicked on reset button of personalization wordpress page. Now my web template is restored by default.

How I can restored the template styles?

[image]

Comment: is that the customizer/site editor? Or is that a page builder plugin? I don't recognise that interface

Comment: Yes is in customizer, sorry, im not speak english!

Comment: the WordPress customizer doesn't look like that, can you be more descriptive? Where is this GUI? How are you accessing it? Is it a feature of your theme/plugin? What is the URL used to access it? What are the personalisation options you're trying to change? Your screenshot is very small and doesn't show much, can you provide a bigger screenshot?